# How to get the content of component in customized listbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to get the content of the hyperlink button clicked in the customized list. The code of XAML is posted below.

```
<ListBox Height="513" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,88,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="73" Width="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/> 
                        <StackPanel Width="370">
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding usrname}" Click="eventhandler" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="24" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding msg}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event handler will have a source argument which is a reference to the `HyperlinkButton`. You can use it as follows:

```
public void eventhandler(object source, EventArgs e)
{
  HyperlinkButton button = source as HyperlinkButton;
  var foo = button.Content;
}
```

Comment: what is "sender", do u mean source ??